# Oracle 19c Table not listed in Crystal Reports 2020 demo

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

I want to learn the construction of reports with Crystal Reports !

I installed Oracle 19c under Windows and Crystal reports demo version.

I created a c##testuser and also a single table WELCOME.

`create table welcome (message varchar2(100));`

`insert into welcome values ('Welcome to Oracle 19c');`

I can see the content of the table with SQL plus or SQL developer

I also granted some privileges to the c##testuser and I can now connect Crystal reports to the pluggable database ORCLPDB whith the c##testuser.

When I try to make a report, I only see AUDSYS, CTXSYS, SYS, SYSTEM and some other tables but not my Welcome Table !!!

I don't realy know what I have to do to see this table.

When someone ca help ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You see the tablespaces not tables. You have to create your own tablespace (for example "test") and add a user (for example "test"). The user should have the roles "connect" and "resoure". The default tablespace should be "test".

Then you login with this new user and create your table "welcome".

In Crystal Reports you login with this user. Now you can open your tablespace and can see the table "welcome".

[image: Crystal Reports database-assistant]

I also recommend to use the connection type "Oracle Server" in Crystal Reports.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer ! I will test it ! I also found another solution by using the Oracle Provider for OLE DB. I can now see the tables created from the c##testuser. Thank you so much for taking the time to respond. I think it both solutions will be very usefull for newbie like me !